# How to get old message formatting in version 11?

Tags: customization, undocumented, message-coding, compatibility

Version 11 uses a new-style message formatting.

[image]

The new style has useful features, and it is usually desirable. However, when saved in a notebook, it doesn't display correctly in older versions of *Mathematica*. If we use version 11 to write documentation for a package that is also compatible with older versions, we cannot include new-style messages in the notebook.

How can we turn off this new message formatting?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We can get old-style messages using

```
Internal`$MessageMenu = False
```

[image]

Needless to say, this is unsupported and undocumented functionality.

Comment: Thanks to WRI support for the information!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I have been going back and forth with tech support with no luck.