# How do I disable the stack tracing feature in Mathematica 11?

Tags: bugs, memory, debugging, error-tracking, clear

**Bug was introduced in 11.0 and persisting through 11.1**

---

It looks like the *Mathematica* 11 stack tracing feature (see red ellipsis in front of any warning message) prevents the garbage collector from removing temporary variables. For example, the following code leaves three copies of `hugeTempVar` in memory after each evaluation.

```
test[a_]:= Module[{hugeTempVar},
    hugeTempVar = ConstantArray[a, 1000];
    a/0; (* some code which produces a message *)
    a
    ];

Table[test[i], {i, 1, 10}];

Names[$Context<>"*$*"]
```

If one removes message-producing code `a/0` there is no memory leak.

In this particular example, one can also use `ParallelTable` to enable old-style messages without a stack trace and thus prevent a memory leak.

I don't want to disable messages, because they provide important diagnostic information.

Is there a possibility to disable stack tracing, but keep the messages?

Comment: The memory leak is reproduced with version 11.0.1 on Windows 7 x64. With version 10.4.1 there is no memory leak.

Comment: I would suggest filing a report with Wolfram on this, I think it's annoying enough that it's worth bringing to their attention and letting them decide.

Comment: See here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/123965/12

Comment: @Kuba The "Stack Trace ..." window which can be opened from the ellipsis in front of the warning message doesn't show the value of `hugeTempVar$541`, it does show the code `hugeTempVar$541 = ConstantArray[1, 1000]` what doesn't require keeping the actual variable  `hugeTempVar$541`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov you see, I missed the point. Let me delete my confusing comments

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to disable stack tracing, but keep messages?

```
Internal`$MessageMenu = False
```

reverts back to the old messages. Seems to do the trick and prevent the leak from my testing.

Answer (score 26):

*Analysis current as of Mathematica version 11.0.1 and 11.1.0.*

We can disable the *Show Stack Trace* item in the new message menu as follows:

```
MessageMenu`$PruneStack;
MessageMenu`Dump`$IncludeStack = False;
```

The reference to `` MessageMenu`$PruneStack `` is there to ensure that the message menu packages have been autoloaded (otherwise our setting will be lost should the packages be loaded later).

Stack information is stored as down-values on the symbol `` MessageMenu`MessageStackList ``.  We can reclaim any memory from earlier messages by executing `ClearAll` on this symbol.  We can also inspect these down values to verify that the `$IncludeStack` setting is taking effect.

Comment: Also works for version 11.1, which is just now being released.