# Local symbols and variables in Module

Tags: scoping, localsymbol

Is it allowed to define local functions inside the `Module` in Mathematica? For example, out of the two codes below which one is correct?

First:

```
plt1[a_, b_] := 
    Module[{x, y},
        f[x_, y_] := Sin[x*y];
        Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}]
    ];


plt1[1, 2]
```

Second:

```
plt2[a_, b_] := 
    Module[{f},
        f[x_, y_] := Sin[x*y];
        Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}]
    ];


plt2[1, 2]
```

Comment: The first one makes x,y local, but f global.  Making x,y, local is not necessary, because Plot3D localizes its variables. The second one makes f local. Therefore, the second one is the right way.

Comment: @Daniel Your point is made very clearly in your comment. Perhaps you could convert it to an answer.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks a lot for the clarifications.

Comment: You have to be careful with local functions like your `f` in the second example, since often (but not in your case above) they will not be automatically garbage-collected. I recommend reading [this Q/A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/221436/what-causes-module-variables-to-leak) for more information on that.

Answer (score 5):

The first example makes x,y local, but f global. Making x,y, local is not necessary, because Plot3D localizes its variables. This leaves f global what can creates troubles.

The second example makes f local and does not unnecessarily localize x and y. Therefore, the second example is the right way.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Have a look at the localized definition of a function using a localized symbol.

```
Module[{f}, f[x_] := x^2; DownValues[f]]
(* {HoldPattern[f$6838[x_]] :> x^2} *)
```

`Module` renames the localized symbols. In this case `f` becomes `f$6838`. You may do the same things with a localized symbol that you can do with a global symbol.