# "Show Stack Trace" option always missing from error context menu

Tags: notebooks, error-tracking, debugging

According to the [Wolfram Language documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/GetAStackTrace.html), there should be an option in the context menu to see the stack trace:

[image: Wolfram Language documentation context menu]

But I never see that option in my context menus:

[image]

Is there a specific global option that I need to turn on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Some commands seem not to produce a stack trace. Some do. (For me.) Give us an example that does not.

Comment: `MoleculeValue`, for one, as indicated in the snippet. On my computer, `MoleculeValue[1, "IsomericSMILES"]` results in an error without that option.

Comment: Please note that the error in the main post is the result of running a much longer sequence of expressions that just this one, so there should be an internal stack.

Comment: `MoleculeValue[1, "IsomericSMILES"]` produces the error and I can see a stack trace on my system.

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140312/4999

Comment: It does indeed. `MessageMenu.$PruneStack` was set to `True` on my system. Thank you!